# How do I find unique values for a specific key in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, unique

I'm using Python 3.7.  I have an array of dictionaries.  All the dictionaries have the same keys, e.g.

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
```

How do I find all the unique values for the key `"a"` for example?  That is, if the array looked like

```
arr = [{"a": 1, "b": 5}, {"a": 1, "b": 3}, {"a": 2, "b": 1}]
```

I would want the result to be

```
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Is the order important?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `set()` for this task:

```
arr = [{"a": 1, "b": 5}, {"a": 1, "b": 3}, {"a": 2, "b": 1}]

print( set(d['a'] for d in arr) )
```

Prints:

```
{1, 2}
```

Or in tuple form:

```
print( tuple(set(d['a'] for d in arr)) )

(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{"a": 1, "b": 5}, {"a": 1, "b": 3}, {"a": 2, "b": 1}]
unique_values = {d['a'] for d in arr}
```